# opening a new tab with a link using window.open() and i want that tab close automatically after 15sec

Tags: javascript

I am using window.open function in a button with onclick event. I want to open link in new tab and new tab should be closed after 15 seconds. So the countdown should be on the current page where button exists.
Code snippet:

```
<button onClick="openlike()">Like</button>
<script>

        function openlike(){
            var likewindow = window.open('http://www.google.com');
        }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

when you open the new window store the window handler in a global variable and after clicking the button use `setTimeout()` function to close the window after several times. In `setTimeout()` function put time in `miliseconds` refers how many times it delay to execute the given function.

```
<button onClick="openlike()">Like</button>

<script>
        var likewindow;
        function openlike(){
            likewindow = window.open('http://www.google.com');
            setTimeout(windowClose,15000);
        }
        function windowClose(){
            likewindow.close();
        }

</script>
```

See the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ataur63/95ky1c4r/1/) for demo.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this way:

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var newWindow = window.open("http://www.w3schools.com");
    setTimeout(() => newWindow.close(), 15 * 1000);
}
</script>
```